# Paypal DG Express Cannot Use Sandbox. Live Account Works Fine

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a Paypal Digital Goods Express payment form created using their wizard.

When I use our live account it works fine. But when I use the sandbox Business (Seller) account I created, when a user clicks on the 'Buy' button, the popup window appears with only this message:

```
SetExpressCheckout API call failed. Detailed Error Message: Short Error Message: Error Code: Error Severity Code:
```

I did some research and saw this article:

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_EN

It suggests that our hosting company needs to update their PHP/TLS, but I did the Curl test and it properly returns a 200 OK.

I also saw this Stackoverflow article:

[Paypal "SetExpressCheckout" API method has stopped working with sandbox seller account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024922/paypal-setexpresscheckout-api-method-has-stopped-working-with-sandbox-seller-a)

...where the problem was the wrong sandbox endpoint, but I've made sure that the endpoint is indeed:

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
```

...and it still doesn't work.

I've tried clearing my browser cache, using different computers to test and all with the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

did you enable Digital Goods feature on your sandbox accounts?
If you have not enabled it on your sandbox account, please contact MTS(Merchant Technical Support)
https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask
to toggle it for your sandbox account.